# Does disabling a .NET control prevent it from posting back

Tags: asp.net, forms, controls

I have a custom made ASP control which is based on a select (drop down menu).  If I disable my control by adding the word "disabled" in its html, I start getting null pointer errors when processing the form data.

I figure, either the browser doesn't post back disabled form items or ASP.NET ignores them when processing the form data.  I'm not sure which one it is.  I'm trying to understand where I'm loosing data.

Thanks for your help.

PS.  I realize that there are better way to create and disable controls than manually editing html but there's a context here that doesn't allow me to do otherwise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes setting control's Enable = false is prevents control's value to be added posted data collection.

you can use [readonly attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/ASPNET/prop_webcontrol_textbox_readonly.asp) instead.

here in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.readonly.aspx) it says :

> The Text value of a TextBox control
>   with the ReadOnly property set to true
>   is sent to the server when a postback
>   occurs, but the server does no
>   processing for a read-only text box.
>   This prevents a malicious user from
>   changing a Text value that is
>   read-only. The value of the Text
>   property is preserved in the view
>   state between postbacks unless
>   modified by server-side code.

Also here is the [Microsoft's reply](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=102065) to a bug report related to topic.

but if you use in classical way like that it will work :

```
txt2.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");
```

Comment: This doesn't work for a select box.  The drop down is grayed out but I can still change the values.  

See: http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/_SELECT_READONLY.html

Comment: The readonly trick doesn't work for me but you've answered my question.  I'll just handle the null values.  Thanks

Comment: I find some resource that explains why it is not worked, and added the tested and working code for textboxes, but I'm not sure about dropdowns.

Answer (score 0):

It will prevent the control from posting back but remember this web paradigm is a client/server technology. A person could modify the client data (HTML and / or Javascript) and force a postback no matter what you send him.

Therefore don't rely on this for security sensitive operations such as money manipulation and so on.

Always do a check on the server-side too for sensitive operations.

Comment: Yes, I enforce things on the data layer as well.  Thanks for the reminder.